# How to open a particular section in a HTML page in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am working on a flask project.
I have a home page that contains About, Problems, and Contact in the navbar. The index.html contains this for the navbar.
The about, problem, and Contact sections are on the same page. So whenever these are clicked, the page scrolls to the corresponding section

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link aaa height" href="#about">About</a>
<a class="nav-link aaa height" href="#problem">Problems</a>
<a class="nav-link aaa height" href="#contact">Contact</a>
</li>
```

Now inside my problems page, I have the same navbar, But when I click the about button, it shows me URL not found. This is my python-flask code.

```
@app.route("/en/index#problem")
def index_about():
    return render_template('index.html#about')
```

How can route to the index page about section from some other page?

Comment: I believe that `<a href="#about">About</a>` is an internal page id reference, so it won't link out to another page, it's just an internal reference to the page already served.  What are you expecting?

Comment: Say, I am on my problems.html page, if I now click the about button in the navbar, it should take me to #about section in index.html

Comment: if you want to navigate from the `problems.html` page to the `index.html` page, then use a link to the `index.html` page and not only `#about`.  You might try,`<a href="/index.html#about">About</a>`

Comment: Did tyou resolve the problem?, I have this problem too.